Why isn’t the term “halacha” found in Tanach?
Halacha is what governs an observant Jews entire life, but the term itself isn’t found in Tanach. Have any commentators written about this? When did the term start being used?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halakha

והלכת בדרכיו״”…
